# Split ExcelSheet after separator

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file, in the first sheet I have on  `column A` some text delimited by a separator, like this:

```
Column A
--------
Text line 1.1
Text line 1.2
Text line 1.3
***
Text line 2.1
Text line 2.2
Text line 2.3
***
Text line 3.1
```

I like to split the content after the `***` separator and put each piece in a separate file with only one sheet. The name of the files should be the first line of the each section.
I need to be able to copy with the formatting, colors, etc.

This is the function but is not copying the formatting...

```
Private Function AImport(ThisWorkbook As Workbook) As Boolean

    Dim height As Long
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim startLine As Long
    Dim endLine As Long
    Dim tmpWs As Worksheet
    Dim AnError As Boolean

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1) 'sheet name "Sheet1"
        height = .Cells(.rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row
        startLine = 6
        nr = 1
        For i = startLine + 1 To height
            If InStr(.Cells(i, 2).Value, "***") > 0 Then
                separate = i
                a = Format(nr, "00000")
                fileName = "File" & a
                endLine = separate - 1
                .rows(startLine & ":" & endLine).Copy
                Set tmpWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                tmpWs.Paste
                tmpWs.Select
                tmpWs.Copy
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False  

                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\Output\" & fileName & " .xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8, CreateBackup:=False 'xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
                ActiveWorkbook.Close
                tmpWs.Delete

                'update next start line
                startLine = separate + 1
                nr = nr + 1
            End If
        Next i

    End With
        If AnError Then
        MsgBox "Errors detected in " & ThisWorkbook.Name & "! Check LogFile.txt file for details. Execution stopped!", vbExclamation, inputWb.Name
        AImport = False
    Else:
        Application.StatusBar = "Workbook check succesfully completed. Executing macro..."
        AImport = True
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give out a workable solution, surely not a good one

```
Sub testing()

    Dim height As Long
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim startLine As Long
    Dim endLine As Long
    Dim tmpWs As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") ' Input your sheet name here
        height = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        startLine = 3
        For i = 2 To height
            If InStr(.Cells(i, 1).Value, "***") > 0 Then
                separate = i
                fileName = .Cells(startLine, 1).Value
                endLine = separate - 1
                .Rows(startLine & ":" & endLine).Copy
                Set tmpWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
                tmpWs.Paste
                tmpWs.Select
                tmpWs.Copy
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ' in the following line, replace the file path with your own
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:="H:\" & fileName & " .xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
                ActiveWorkbook.Close
                tmpWs.Delete

                'update next start line
                startLine = separate + 1
            End If
        Next i

        'handline the last section here
        endLine = height
        fileName = .Cells(startLine, 1).Value
        .Rows(startLine & ":" & endLine).Copy
        Set tmpWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        tmpWs.Paste
        tmpWs.Select
        tmpWs.Copy
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:="H:\" & fileName & " .xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        tmpWs.Delete

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I need to be able to copy with the formatting, colors, etc. How can I do that?!Now i get some ugly colors!

Comment: @Adrian
Hi, can you update your sample data above? I have tested with my code on your sample over again. The formatting, text color are copied.

Comment: @Adrian Hi, I have copied your marco and your test data, put them into Column B and run the code. I still have the text color copied into the new xls file. 

But some minor points I would like to point out.    "ThisWorkbook" is a reserved keyword in Excel-VBA. I changed it to currentWorkbook
And remember to hanlde the last section
And making sure the /output directory exist.

Comment: Hi, Anyway I have put the colors back so, it is good.
But it seems that there is a problem if you make some background coloring, font color etc ...

Comment: I have no idea, it's working just fine for me. Maybe you can copy the code and raise another question, the PROs might have a clue

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

This code dumps the files to single sheet `csv` files under a directory held by `strDir`, "C:temp" in this example

```
Sub ParseCOlumn()
Dim X
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFName As String
Dim strText As String
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim lngStart As Long
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFSOFile As Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
strDir = "C:\temp"
X = Application.Transpose(Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))

'test for first record not being "***"
lngStart = 1
If X(1) <> "***" Then
strFName = X(1)
lngStart = 2
End If

For lngRow = lngStart To UBound(X)
If X(lngRow) <> "***" Then
If Len(strText) > 0 Then
strText = strText & (vbNewLine & X(lngRow))
Else
strText = X(lngRow)
End If
Else
Set objFSOFile = objFSO.createtextfile(strDir & "\" & strFName & ".csv")
objFSOFile.write strText
objFSOFile.Close
strFName = X(lngRow + 1)
lngRow = lngRow + 1
strText = vbNullString
End If
Next
'dump last record
If X(UBound(X)) <> "***" Then
Set objFSOFile = objFSO.createtextfile(strDir & "\" & strFName & ".csv")
objFSOFile.write strText
End If
objFSOFile.Close

End Sub
```